# I would like to update my SQL Server table depending upon a value in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Let's just say I have two rows in a table with `ID` and `Amount` columns. If my `ID` starts with `Crd` or `CRDT`, then I need to multiply the `Amount` with -1 for that particular row.

```
ID      Amount 
--------------
crd12     9
123      10
crdt123  99
```

Result I need

```
ID      Amount 
--------------
crd12     -9
123       10
crdt123  -99
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [MyTable] 
SET [Amount] = -[Amount] 
WHERE 
    [ID] LIKE 'crd%'
    AND [Amount] > 0
```

Comment: How to do it immediately after inserting the data into the table ? I have to do this for thousands of records. I have tried  UPDATE Table              SET [Amount] = -1* [Amount] 

Where ID LIKE 'Crd%' AND InvoiceNumber LIKE 'Crdt%'  but I am not sure why it is not working

Comment: You could do it in a trigger... but I suggest you fix your application.

Comment: Or just do it in a view and don't touch the data.

Comment: As a high rep user, you should know that others like an explanation. Please try to edit some lines into this to explain what the code actually does.